# django - dynamic query on form field

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Lets say I have a form with some fields. I was wondering if it is possible to do dynamic query where I could do a string match while the user is typing into a field. Like when typing into google it returns a list of choices when you type into the search bar. Can someone give me an example on how and where to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking to achieve is fields for a `ForeignKey` then you can provide a `Queryset` on the form field then use an app like [`django_select2`](https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2) which can then provide a widget which will allow a user to search for items in the `Queryset` for the field. e.g.

```
city = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=City.objects.all(),
    label=u"City",
    widget=ModelSelect2Widget(
        model=City,
        search_fields=['name__icontains'],
        dependent_fields={'country': 'country'},
        max_results=500,
    )
)
```

Then in the form, as you started to type into the `city` field it'd start to search on `City.name` using an `icontains` lookup. The docs for this are [here](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra.html).

If that's not what you're looking for then you could just write some Javascript which detected input to a field, then sent an ajax request to a view with the contents of your field. That could then return a response which displayed content in the page related to the input.

Comment: In my case, the form field will not be a foreignkey field to the field I want search on. Is something like that possible? Ultimately the idea would to preform the string match as they type into a field 'description' and if they click on an existing description that matches what they need then it will auto populate the item code that matches that corresponding description. But the user also needs the flexibility of typing descriptions outside of the existing ones.

Comment: @K.Pardo I think Select2 can do that for you, because you'll just give it an iterable of things to search I suspect. Take a look over the docs here; https://select2.org/